# Ansible apt-get install output

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I am using vagrant with an ansible playbook to automatically install a bunch of programs on an ubuntu image. One program is failing to install on the vagrant VM. In the `Vagrant` file I have

```
config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
  ansible.verbose = "vvv"
  ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
end
```

but the verbose output does not include the `apt-get` output. My playbook.yml looks like

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: true
  tasks:
    - name: get vi
      apt: state=latest name=vim
```

How can I see the console output of an individual (or all) `apt-get install`'s on the VM since ansible instead outputs each install in the format

```
TASK: [Install vim] *********************************************************** 
failed: [default] => {"failed": true}
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register to a variable the output of the apt module execution and then print it.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  sudo: true
  tasks:
    - name: get vi
      apt: state=latest name=vim
      register: aptout

    # show the content of aptout var
    - debug: var=aptout
```

Answer (score 8):

## Reproducing the `stdout` of `apt`

Here is how to reproduce the `stdout` of `apt`…

```
---
- name: 'apt: update & upgrade'
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
    cache_valid_time: 3600
    upgrade: safe
  register: apt
- debug: msg={{ apt.stdout.split('\n')[:-1] }}
```

…with nice line breaks, thanks to `.split('\n')`, and omitting the last empty string with `[:-1]`, all of which is Python string manipulation, of course.

```
"msg": [
    "Reading package lists...", 
    "Building dependency tree...", 
    "Reading state information...", 
    "Reading extended state information...", 
    "Initializing package states...", 
    "Building tag database...", 
    "No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.", 
    "0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.", 
    "Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.", 
    "Reading package lists...", 
    "Building dependency tree...", 
    "Reading state information...", 
    "Reading extended state information...", 
    "Initializing package states...", 
    "Building tag database..."
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use directly `stdout_lines`, after registering the output as also shown above, but you must make sure that `apt` did output something, for example, it installed something, otherwise that element is not defined. Here's a possible example:

```yaml
- name: Install Gnome Packages
  become: yes
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
    state: latest
    pkg:
    - gnome-tweaks
    - dconf-editor
    - guake
  register: aptout

- debug: msg="{{ aptout.stdout_lines }}"
  when: aptout.stdout_lines is defined
```

Answer (score 1):

In the version of ansible I'm using at the moment, `ansible-playbook -v` seems sufficient to get apt output.  Admittedly I haven't tested failures.  The output is in the form of JSON, which makes it a bit hard to read (as the other answer works around).

The Ansible version I tested was 2.3.2.0.